# how to reload a div tag after submit?

Tags: javascript, html

how to reload a div tag after submit?

Comment: use AJAX... or give some more details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - well worth learning to simplify dealing with all things JavaScript.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "bin/process.php",  
     data: $(this).serialize(),  
     success: function() {  
       $('#mydiv').load('some/url/for/data');
     }  
   });
```

1. submit form data (formatted using [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to prevent page refresh
2. reload your div content in the success event handler